Froala content changes after page load
I have a Froala control in my page that is potentially empty, or filled with previously saved content. I also have a dirty check in place to compare the before and after of the field when there are changes made.
Sample of content previously saved:
<div style="font-size: 12px;">test123</div>
Expected behavior:
On page load, the data loaded into the Froala control should remain untouched, and pristine. It should still be:
<div style="font-size: 12px;">test123</div>
Actual behavior:
After the page loads, Froala changes the content, making it dirty, and updates it as follows:
<div style="font-size: 12px;"><div style="font-size: 12px;">test123</div></div>
Steps to reproduce the problem:
Load the page with previously saved data.
This also occurs when an empty control is loaded - for some reason, Froala inputs a space and a new line (as can be seen when using HTML view mode, and highlighting the "empty" content).
Editor version: 4.2.1
Browser: Edge (latest version)
Honestly I'm not sure what to do here - I don't see any option in Froala's options that lets me tell it NOT to change content.

Your problem concerns a bug in the editor, which was resolved in the new release of Froala version 4.3.
According to the release, the version resolved the issue where setting fontSizeDefaultSelection in the config results in multiple wrapper divs added to the content on subsequent edits.
By updating to the new version, you can be confident that this issue will be resolved. This is the most effective solution to your problem.
After updating the version, some approaches keep your code from issues like these:

Check for Redundant Formatting
Use html.set to load content programmatically
Check for Cleaning Options
Preventing Empty Space/Line Addition
Dirty Check Improvement

I'm confident that these actions will fix your issue.

Are you affiliated with the development of Froala? If this is so, then please state your affiliation in the answer, so people know this is a trustworthy answer.
